# Have md-tab-group in a component that receives md-tab children through ng-content?

Tags: angular, angular-material2

To remove some code duplication, we're trying to have a component with `md-tab-group` with an `ng-content` inside of it, so it can receive a few `md-tab` children.

We also need `md-tab-group` in a parent component because it will be handling some analytic events and we'd like to only have this parent component to inject the analytics service and deal with this logic.

I thought this would be as simple as using:

```
<!-- ... a bunch of extra stuff and tags for the component + -->
<md-tab-group>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</md-tab-group>
```

But when I try to use it passing the `md-tab` children, these children won't render:

```
<app-tabbed-section
  class="my-classes"
  [param]="param1"
  title="Another parameter"
>
  <md-tab label="Tab 1">tab with dynamic content 1</md-tab>
  <md-tab label="Tab 2">tab with dynamic content 2</md-tab>
</app-tabbed-section>
```

I believe this is a simple thing to do, so I'm probably missing something here. Any ideas on how to make it work?

Comment: Please elaborate on how you are passing the `md-tab` children through `ng-content`.

Comment: So `md-tab-group` exists in the parent component, and `app-tabbed-section` is a component that holds tab children? If so, how are you connecting the two, and what is `ng-content` for?

Comment: I was expecting to see `ng-content` be replaced by those two `md-tab` components.

Comment: It is still unclear to me what `app-tabbed-section` is. Looking at your .ts files that define components would also be helpful.

Comment: `tabbed-section.component.ts` doesn't contain much. Actually, I just need it to have an `@Input` for its title. I thought that I would be able to just use `ng-content` on its template and when using it, would be able to pass a couple of `md-tabs` to it.